# In Python 3, pip cannot install modules

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-sphinx

I'm getting the SSL error when trying to install a module using pip and I've looked around on the net and found the common solution for that problem:

```
C:\Python35> pip3 install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org sphinx
```

However, running this command did not work as I thought. What am I doing wrong?

```
C:\Python35> pip3 install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org -vvv sphinx
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Collecting sphinx
  1 location(s) to search for versions of sphinx:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/sphinx/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/sphinx/
  Starting new HTTP connection (1): pypi.python.org
  "GET /simple/sphinx/ HTTP/1.1" 403 16
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/sphinx/: 403 Client Error: SSL is required for url: http://pypi.python.org/simple/sphinx/ - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sphinx (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for sphinx
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 514, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for sphinx
```

---

As Mukul Sharma wrote, using

C:\Python35>pip3 install --index-url=**https**://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org -vvv sphinx

instead fixed my problem.

Comment: Try upgrading pip `pip install --upgrade pip` or use this `pip install packagename=version --allow-unverified packagename`, since some packages contain unverified files.

Comment: C:\Python35>pip3 install --upgrade --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org pip3
Collecting pip3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3

Comment: Use this `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Comment: C:\Python35>pip3 install --upgrade pip3
Collecting pip3
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip3/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3

Comment: pip3 install --upgrade pip still give me the  [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]  error, however it also tells me that my pip is up to date

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4205)? It is strongly advised not to use `--trusted-host` because you'll then be vulnerable in MitM attacks. Maybe the comment of dstufft will be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has stopped support on requests using HTTP. They are only allowing requests over HTTPS. You can read more about it [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031714.html).

Just use *https* instead of *http* here:

```
C:\Python35> pip3 install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org sphinx
```

Comment: @Ephreal I mean just marked my answer an 'answer' if it works, will post the cause also

Comment: @Ephreal done. You might want to check out the cause too

Comment: Python? Do you mean the website *python.org*?